# How to disable print screen in windows app

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing an UWP app and I need to disable any method of print screening the app (print screen, snipping tool etc).

How can I do this? Anything from temporarily disabling the app when in focus or just print screening with a black screen works(right now when i alt tab the app goes black).

I tried catching the event but for some reason the print screen key isn't handled the same as the rest.

Comment: @martinstoeckli not only external devices, but other processes could grab the whole screen. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=netframework-4.7.2&term=CopyFromScreen BTW, you could post an "not paossible because of XXX" answer

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/disable-screen-capture-00efe630

Comment: @HansPassant - That's interesting, so my answer was clearly wrong and I deleted it, you should write the correct answer then. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant that worked, can you add it as a reply so i can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `IsScreenCaptureEnabled` property of the [ApplicationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.isscreencaptureenabled) class to `false`

`ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.IsScreenCaptureEnabled = false;`

from MSDN:

> ApplicationView.IsScreenCaptureEnabled Property
>
> This property lets you protect against unwanted copies of the window.
> When screen capture is disabled for a window, the window appears black
> in images produced by screen capture operations. For an example of
> setting the isScreenCaptureEnabled property, see the [Disable screen capture sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DisablingScreenCapture).